# Configuring .htaccess RedirectMatch to play nice with subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a rule in .htaccess configured like this:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ http://www.foosite.com/content/
```

It was put in so that anything going to the root of my site would instead go to the "content" folder.

Today I set up a subdomain called "dev.foosite.com" which I plan on using to hold an exact copy of the normal site, so I can do development work.

Problem is, when I surf to dev.foosite.com it is being redirected to www.foosite.com/content/

I just don't know enough about how these rules work, and I feel stupider after attempting to read the documentation.

How do I set up .htaccess for the following:

1. anytime someone goes to www.foosite.com it should redirect to www.foosite.com/content/
2. anytime someone goes to dev.foosite.com it should redirect to dev.foosite.com/content/

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the `RedirectMatch` directive set up so that it produces a redirect to an absolute URL, and what you really need is a relative URL -- that is, the redirect should not replace the URL's original hostname, so that it'll work regardless of which site it's invoked on. To do that, change the RedirectMatch line (ideally on both sites, but at least on the dev subdomain) to:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ /content/
```

(Changing `www.foosite.com` to `dev.foosite.com` in the dev site's `.htaccess` would have the same effect, but you'd need to change it again should you ever modify the subdomain name or make another copy of the site. The change described above avoids that gotcha.)

One other note regarding a possible enhancement, should you be interested: Your directive presently discards any path information, so that if someone goes to e.g. `http://[www|dev].foosite.com/old/path/to/page.html`, she'll be redirected to `.../content/`, and not to `.../page.html`; in order to preserve path information, assuming it's desirable to do so, you could:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*)$ /content/$1
```

or something similar, assuming a) that there was ever a time when URLs on your site didn't require `/content/`, and b) that there is a consistent way to map between the old URL convention and the new.

Comment: You sir, are awesome.  Thank you so much for helping me with that.  In my case both the production site and dev site are in the same domain, the dev.foosite.com domain is simply a subdomain.  So your first example ^/$ /content/ was all that was needed.  Thank you!!

Comment: Always glad to be of help.